# How to Select Graphics From Graphics Layer Inside a Clicked Circle

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2yj2qvxu/) and let me know how I can get geometry of selected Graphics which are inside the clicked circle extent

```
var map;
var baseCircle;
require([
  "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
  "esri/tasks/query", "esri/geometry/Circle", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Point",
  "esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
  "esri/config", "esri/Color", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, FeatureLayer,
  GraphicsLayer,
  Query, Circle, SpatialReference, Point,
  Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol,
  SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer,
  esriConfig, Color, dom
) {
  esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";

  map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    basemap: "streets",
    center: [-88.158805, 41.786075],
    zoom: 14,
    slider: false
  });

  var pointGLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
  //pointGLayer.setRenderer(pointRenderer);
  map.addLayer(pointGLayer);

  var data = [
    [-88.13198711899997, 41.79304797900005],
    [-88.13559945399999, 41.79100138000007],
    [-88.13565587999994, 41.79234125500005],
    [-88.13645828899996, 41.79017487800007],
    [-88.13801440299994, 41.790968630000066],
    [-88.13797007499994, 41.791996288000064],
    [-88.13798992699998, 41.79258648200005],
    [-88.12837351899998, 41.79370832500007]
  ]
  var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
    SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,
    12,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(
      SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
      new Color([247, 34, 101, 0.9]),
      1
    ),
    new Color([207, 34, 171, 0.5])
  );

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pt = new Point(data[i][0], data[i][1], new SpatialReference({
      wkid: 4326
    }));
    var graphic = new Graphic(pt, symbol);
    pointGLayer.add(graphic);

  }
  var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
    SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,
    12,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(
      SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
      new Color([247, 34, 101, 0.9]),
      1
    ),
    new Color([207, 34, 171, 0.5])
  );


  var circleSymb = new SimpleFillSymbol(
    SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(
      SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SHORTDASHDOTDOT,
      new Color([105, 105, 105]),
      2
    ), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25])
  );
  var circle;

  map.on("click", function(evt) {
    baseCircle = evt.mapPoint;
    console.log(baseCircle);
    circle = new Circle({
      center: evt.mapPoint,
      geodesic: true,
      radius: 1000,
      radiusUnit: "esriMeters"
    });
    map.graphics.clear();
    var graphic = new Graphic(circle, circleSymb);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);

    var query = new Query();
    query.geometry = circle.getExtent();

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample code: [Select graphic points within an extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/graphics_extent_query.html). If you want to select the graphics inside a graphicsLayer, like the object `map.graphics` is, you have to go one by one.

```
    function findPointsInExtent(extent) {
    var results = [];
    dojo.forEach(map.graphics.graphics,function(graphic){
      if (extent.contains(graphic.geometry)) {
        graphic.setSymbol(highlightSymbol);
        results.push(graphic.getContent());
      }
      //else if point was previously highlighted, reset its symbology
      else if (graphic.symbol == highlightSymbol) {
        graphic.setSymbol(defaultSymbol);
      }
    });
```

On the other hand, the most common way to perform selections and so on is to use a `FeatureLayer` instead of a `GraphicsLayer`, and perform a query against it. You have a nice example about that [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_buffer.html)